# How to plot n-dimensional TimeSeries data object?

Tags: plotting, data, visualization, time-series

I have a spectrometer which is generating time-series data every 100ms. I'd like to analyze/plot this data in Mathematica, but I'm not certain the best way to do it.

It's in this form:

```
   | 300 | 301 | ... | 700|
0  | y0  | y1  | ... | yn |
100| ... | ... | ... | ...|
```

I can import the data and extract it just fine

```
data = Import["testingdata.txt","TSV"];
wavelength = data[[30,3;;]];
unixtime = data[[31;;,2]];
absorbance = data[[31;;,3;;]];
```

Where the file headers take up rows 1;;29.

Naively using `ListPlot` to plot `absorbance` does provide a time series result, but I was wondering if there's a way to create a `TimeSeries` object to store this multidimensional data ([TimeSeries Documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeries.html)). Looking at the Docs, it looks like I would have to create a `TimeSeries` object for each wavelength in my spectrum, which is not ideal. Is there a better way to do this? I see that the `TemporalData` function is a more generalized version of `TimeSeries` but it doesn't seem to have support for `{t_i,v_i1,v_i2...}` data.

Edit 1: Per @Domen's comment, `TimeSeries` *does* support arrays:

```
ts = TimeSeries[Transpose[{unixtime,absorbance}]]
```

Edit 2: I created a 3D plot showing essentially how I'd like to visualize the data, but I want to condense it down to 2D.
[image]

Comment: How exactly do you want to analyze data? Your objective(s) will determine what is the best way to store and represent your data. As stated in the documentation, _The values vi can be scalars or arrays of any dimension, but must all be of equal dimensionality._ Therefore, you can store all the absorbance values in one ``TimeSeries`` object. ``ts = TimeSeries[Transpose[{unixtime, absorbance}]]``

Comment: For the analysis, I'd like to look at the time evolution of the system. I think I can do that pretty easily without using the TimeSeries function by just iterating using `Table`, but I'd like to visualize the data in a ListPlot where the x axis is wavelength, and all of the absorbance traces are coplotted and colored according to their timestamp.

Answer (score 7):

**TemporalData** is exactly what you need. You just need to put your data in the proper format. Start from separating your time staps:

```
times = Range[0, 1000, 100];
```

Then put values as a List of Lists (matrix), for example some made up values:

```
values = Table[k + RandomReal[1, 11], {k, 5}]
```

[image]

Now your data are constructed as

```
data = TemporalData[values, {times}]
```

Alternatively, because your time stamps are regular you could just do:

```
data = TemporalData[values, {0, 1000, 100}]
```

Now plot (note, you can also use **DateListPlot** if your time stamps are in a proper time-unit format):

```
ListLinePlot[data, PlotTheme -> "Business"]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not certain this is exactly what I want. When I apply this method to the data, it plots with time as the x axis instead of wavelength, which results in some very odd plots. I think I may be overcomplicating things by trying to make my data into a `TimeSeries` or `TemporalData` object. The plot that I added to the question shows essentially how I'd like the data to end up when plotted.